# Change M000 to current month and M001 to next month name

Tags: python, monthcalendar

I have data df with a column called Month, in these cells are M000 and M001 I need to change all of them to current month name for M000 and next month name for M001

I can rename the data but need to automate this

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of the problem are you struggling with? Applying some change to a column in a DataFrame? Replacing a text like `'M000'` with the current month? Determining the current month? Please share your code so far and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.